# How to connect multiple schema at a time in the single database using java code

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I have a scenario like,

connecting multiple dbuser nothing but schema at a time to a same database using java code,
the tables from 2 schema i have to join using Java,please let me know how to do.

```
For ex :
emp_stg schema
emp table 
Id and name


Dept_stg schema
dept table
Deptno,Id,
```

IN oracle we can login to another schema using dot operator,
for ex now m in EMP dbuser,i have to connect the table from dept db user
 the query is like dis

```
select id,deptno from emp,dept_stg.dept
```

this query i have to run using Java JDBC,so I used proeperty file where i had given JDBC connection to database but i am nt able to connect mutiple schema in a single property file
anyone could plz help

Answer (score 0):

In the given example you are not logging into a second schema. The owner (or a user with the necessary rights respectively) of schema "dept_stg" has granted the SELECT right on table dept to another schema - here emp_stg. This allows the schema/user emp_stg to query the table in the other schema.

So this refers to database only. You can create a connection to the database using Java and use the credentials just for schema emp_stg. No multiple connections are required. Since this user has the right to access the second schema, you should send the query

```
SELECT id, deptno FROM emp, dept_stg.dept
```

without any problems.